# Creating a semi-ring with tapered ends all with CSS

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to figure out if this is possible with CSS. I've seen some really creative and crazy shapes people have been making and this doesn't seem too far off.

*I want to be able to create this red ring with css.*

I think the route I have been going which is trying a semi-ellipse is doomed from the start because I have no way to knock out the center, I could draw a smaller ellipse within this ellipse with a transparent background but the original ellipse bg color would show.

Current Approach:

`.ring{
    background: orange;
    width:250px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50% / 100%;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    transform:rotate(-65deg);
    margin-left:-75px;
}`

**What I need is to be able to create some kind of tapered elliptical stroke.**

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/clovola/0j7dgc2c/

[image: What I'm trying to acheive.]

Comment: It's possible, but why do you need to do this in CSS?

Comment: Why ask why when how is so much more fun?

Comment: Well, if you are asking this for a practical application CSS isn't the way to go. But if you are just doing it for fun then that's fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created a starting point for you to work from (it's no fun if someone else does everything, right?):

http://jsfiddle.net/0j7dgc2c/6/

Essentially, you'll need learn more about CSS `transform`. You can rotate around specific axes and use matrix transformations.

```
.ring{
    width:200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: solid orange;
    border-width: 15px 0 15px 25px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transform: rotateY(45deg);
    margin-left:-75px;
}
```

Comment: You are correct. I do need to learn more about transform. I was aware of rotate but hadn't noticed rotateY/X, and the border approach is good as well.